# How to restrict a user from renaming a file in android?

Tags: java, android, file

I am creating an app on Android. In my app, I create some folders and files and then fetch those files to do some work. I fear that if any user renames it, then my app will stop working.

How to restrict the user from renaming that file? If it is not possible, then I'd appreciate any alternate suggestions.

Comment: Try saving to the Internal Storage instead? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: you can make also an 'encrypted' zipfile-like folder. it will take some more time to extract the files you need. you will get fewer chances your program gets corrupted with bad intentions. altering files cant be stopped

Comment: @WvdL, I tried it but it is taking lot of code to work, but i like the of creating it in Internal Storage

Comment: What if the user doesn't have enough Internal memory.....please help still not getting it.